# Count down the images when load the view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I want count down the images when the view will load.for that purpose i delayed all the functions when the view will load.i did in view load

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 //-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=Count Down Numbers animation-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    NumImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"03.png"],         [UIImage imageNamed:@"02.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"], nil];
    NumImageView.animationDuration =4;

    [numView addSubview:NumImageView];

    [NumImageView startAnimating]; 
.......//remaining code

}
```

Here i dropped NumImageView is `UIImageView` on numView.

but not getting all images.3 and 1 animating the remaining 2 image not showing. Actually this is correct process or using `NSThread` is correct process but i don't now how to use `NSThread`.

Comment: i dont quite follow your question, but i can tell you now that you dont want to do UI stuff on a different thread, all UI animations and changes should happen on the main thread

Comment: ok but how to animate the images like count down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also achieve this with animation blocks which move to the next animation when completion is reached like in this method:

```
- (void)animateCountDown
{
    //first add numImageView
    [numView addSubview:numImageView];
    //add first image
    numImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"03.png"];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^
    {
        numImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"02.png"];
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
                     {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^
                          {
                              numImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"];
                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished)
                                          {
                                              //start whatever after countdown
                                           }];
                     }];
}
```

Then call this in your `viewDidLoad` like this `[self animateCountDown];`

Another way to do it is by using `NSTimer`. I made an example so you can see how to use this as you see fit. In this example the `NSTimer` is calling the `countMethod` which decrements the `count integer` that sets the correct `UIImage` to the `UIImageView`, the `countMethod` also checks if the `count integer` goes under 1 so it can `invalidate` the `NSTimer` and you have a place to call a method to start the rest of your application.

Sounds like a lot to take in but look at this screenshot and all is clear:

[image: NSTimerexample]

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to do something like this, i dont know the details of your implementation, but im sure you can figure it out

```
//add all images into an array with
NSArray *NumImageView = @{img1, img2, img3, img4}; //these are UIImageViews that you have made previously

for(int i = 0; i < NumImageView.count; i++){
     [numView addSubview:NumImageView[i]]; //add all images
     NumImageView[i].hidden = true; //make them hidden initially
}

for(int i = 0; i < NumImageView.count; i++){

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:i*1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        NumImageView[i].hidden = false; //unhide when it starts aniamting

        //animate image coming in

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        UIImageView *image = NumImageView[i];
        [image removeFromSuperView]; //remove current number
    }];
}
```

Comment: here r u not adding images to imageView adding to array and add to view....but .hidden and removeFromSuperView  property not founded error occured

Comment: probably need to cast the array element back into the appropriate type, ill make an edit. img1, img2 etc, should be UIImageViews or whatever type you want

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(void)viewdidload
{
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(animateImages) toTarget:self withObject:nil]
}

-(void)animateImages
{
//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=Count Down Numbers animation-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    NumImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"03.png"],         [UIImage imageNamed:@"02.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"], nil];
    NumImageView.animationDuration =4;

    // repeat the annimation forever
    NumImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
   [NumImageView startAnimating];
    [numView addSubview:NumImageView];


.......//remaining code
}
```

Comment: 3,2,1 animation repeating.when take the count 1 it will show animate 1 time only